# Why does MIPS BLT cause Exception 7?

Tags: arrays, assembly, max, mips, min

I am getting an error where blt is causing my program to crash with the exception 7.

It occurs in PMIN

The purpose of this program is to take in up to 100 integers from the user. once the integers have been entered and a negative value enters to stop the collection loop then the sum and min are displayed

```
        .data
MSG:    .asciiz "Enter integer values, one per\nline, terminated by a         
negative\nvalue.\n"
EMSG:   .asciiz "The program has terminated."
SUM:    .asciiz "     Sum is: "
MIN:    .asciiz "     Min is: "
MAX:    .asciiz "     Max is: "
MEAN:   .asciiz "    Mean is: "
VAR:    .asciiz "Variance is: "
CR:     .byte   '\n'
        .align 2
ARRAY:  .space  400
        .align 2
        .text
        .globl main


main:

li          $t1,0               #Element counter
li          $t2,0               #Max Elements
li          $t3,0               #Mem counter
li          $v0,4               #Syscall print message
la          $a0,MSG             #MSG
syscall


LOOP:

li          $v0,5               #Syscall accept user input
syscall
blt         $v0,$zero,CSUM      #If input is less than zero branch to     CSUM
sw          $v0,ARRAY($t3)      #Store user input into array at space     t3
addiu       $t3,$t3,4           #Add 4 to mem counter
addiu       $t1,$t1,1           #Add 1 to element counter
addiu       $t2,$t2,1           #Add 1 to max elements
bne         $t1,100,LOOP        #Branch back to LOOP if t1 != 100


CSUM:

li          $t1,0               #Set t1 back to 0
li          $t3,0               #Set t3 back to 0
li          $t5,0               #Total sum
A:
lw          $s0,ARRAY($t3)      #Store Array element t3 into s0
add         $t5,$t5,$s0         #Add Array element stored in s0 to t5
addiu       $t3,$t3,4           #Add 4 to mem counter
addiu       $t1,$t1,1           #Add 1 to element counter
bne         $t1,$t2,A           #If t1 != t2 branch to A


PSUM:

li          $v0,4               #Syscall print message
la          $a0,SUM             #SUM
syscall
li          $v0,1               #Syscall print integer
move        $a0,$t5             #Move t5 to a0
syscall
li          $v0,11              #Syscall print byte
lb          $a0,CR              #CR
syscall


PMIN:
li          $t1,0               #Set t1 back to 0
li          $t3,0               #Set t3 back to 0
addiu       $t6,$t2,-1
B:
lw          $s2,ARRAY($t3)
addiu       $t1,$t1,1
addiu       $t3,$t3,4
lw          $s3,ARRAY($t3)
blt         $s3,$s2,MI
blt         $s2,$s3,MI
bne         $t6,$t1,B
j           PrintMIN
MI:
move        $s5,$s2
j           B


PrintMIN:

li          $v0,4
la          $a0,MIN
syscall
li          $v0,1
move        $a0,$s5


EXIT:
li      $v0,4                   #Syscall print message
la      $a0,EMSG                #EMSG
syscall
jr      $ra                     #Exit
```

Comment: Which instruction actually faults?  You're running this on MARS or SPIM with branch-delay slots disabled, right?  BTW, two `blt` instructions in a row with opposite conditions is equivalent to `bne` for integers, because either `a<b`, `b<a`, or `a==b`.  (Unlike for floating point, where unordered is possible so all three of those comparisons are false.)

Comment: _"Why does MIPS BLT cause Exception 7?"_ It doesn't. If you look at what the simulator is telling you, the exception actually occurs at `lw $s3,ARRAY($t3)`. Presumably because the offset stored in `$t3` is out of bounds.